# How to get or retrive keys/secrets from azure key vault by using spring boot application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Unable to get the correct solution with similar posts

Here I'm facing problem, while passing the only uri in properties File application is not wokring.
Get or post cal is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the secrets for your application you can configure the following steps

We have to enable **managed identity** for our application

[image]

here we can see the loaded secrets to the **keyvault** as below
[image]

From the Secrets we can select anyone of the secret to see the data as below:
[image]

[image]

So we can control the distribution of secrets to reduce any accidental leakage by centralizing storage of application secrets, Only application can securely access the secrets. Because everything is controlled using RBAC to the keyword.

When an app is loading secrets it will be authenticated and authorized using Azure active directory and [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli) we can monitor the access and use of secrets in keyword.

For more information please refer the below Microsoft documentation:

. [Deploy your first Azure Spring Cloud application| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/quickstart?tabs=Azure-CLI&pivots=programming-language-java&WT.mc_id=java-00000-ropreddy) .

. [Read a secret from Azure Key Vault in a Spring Boot application | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault) .

Comment: Hi Ajay,  thanks for ur reply. I have mentioned key vault URL and client I'd, tenent id in the application properties and already I have added secrets in azure key vault. I deployed my changes but am facing 503 service reponse. Need to run any azure cli commands to set the permissions or need to enable managed identify is enough. Plz let me know if there any other configuration is required.

Comment: Hello @Srinivas we can enable managed identity.